# Enforce strict consistency spanning multiple aggregates

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate, eventual-consistency

Consider the following business requirements:

***We have players which can play games. A player can play only one game at a time. A game needs two players.***

The system will contain millions of players, and games take about two minutes. Concurrency issues are likely to emerge.

We want to comply to the rule that a **single transaction involves a single aggregate**. Further, eventual consistency must not lead to accepted games which must be cancelled afterwards (even if a short period of time) due to concurrency issues. Thus, eventual consistency is not really appropriate.

How do we need to define the aggregates and their boundaries to enforce these business rules?

I conceived two approaches:

**1. Event-based handshake**

Aggregate `Player`, aggregate `Game`.

When a game is requested, it pushed a `GameRequested`-event. The `Player`s subscribe this event and respond with a corresponding event, either `GamePlayerAccepted` or `GamePlayerRejected`. Only if both `Player`s have accepted, the `Game` starts (`GameStarted`).

*Pros:*

- The aggregate `Player` is responsible for managing his own availability which corresponds to the domain model

*Cons:*

- The responsibility of starting a `Game` is scattered throughout multiple aggregates (it seems like "fake"-eventual-consistency)
- Much communication overhead
- Consistency measures needed, e.g. freeing up the `Player`s if something went wrong

**2. Collection-aggregate**

Aggregate `Player`, aggregate `GamesManager` (with a collection of value-objects `ActiveGamePlayers`), aggregate `Game`.

The `GameManager` is requested to start a new `Game` with two given `Player`s. The `GameManager` is able to ensure that a `Player` only plays once at a time since it's a single aggregate.

*Pros:*

- No consistency-enforcing events such as `GamePlayerAccepted`, `GamePlayerRejected` and so forth

*Cons:*

- The domain model seems obscured
- The responsibility of the `Player` to manage availability shifted
- We have to ensure that only one instance of `GameManager` is created and introduce domain-mechanisms which let the client not worry about the intermediary-aggregate
- Independent `Game`-starts disrupt each other because the `GameManager`-aggregate locks itself
- Need for performance optimization since the `GameManager`-aggregate collects all active game players which will be tens of millions

It seems like none of these approaches are appropriate to solve the problem. I don't know how to set the boundaries to ensure both strict consistency and clarity of the model, and performance.

Comment: You might review your decision to be very dogmatic about your transaction boundaries. Sometimes you bend the rules. If dogmas prevent you from delivering the value - it is not a good sign.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev What would you suggest?

Comment: I have no direct suggestion since I do not know a lot about your domain. There are many ways to fix this. Some use pre-handling application cache, which would prevent you from sending potentially failing commands, just one of the options. It is ok to have some constraints also outside of the domain model. Or you can use a transaction. Or you can use a routing slip with compensating actions.

Answer (score 2):

**I would go with the event-based handshake and this is how I would implement:**

From what I understand you would need a `Game` process implemented as a `Saga`. You will also have to define a `Player` aggregate, a `RequestGame` command, a `GameRequested` event, a `GameAccepted` event, a `GameRejected` event, a `MarkGameAsAccepted` command, a `MarkGameAsRejected` command, a `GameStarted` event and a `GameFailed` event.

So, when the `Player A` want's to play a game with `Player B`, `Player A` receives the `RequestGame` command. If this player is playing something else then a `PlayerAlreadyPlaysAGame` exception is thrown, otherwise it raises the `GameRequested` event and update it's internal state as `playing`.

The `Game` saga catches the `GameRequested` event and send the `RequestGame` command to the `Player B` aggregate (this is a `Player` aggregate with `ID` equal to `A`). Then:

- If the `Player B` is playing another game (it knows this by querying its internal `playing` state) then it raises the `GameRejected` event; the `Game` saga catches this event and send a `MarkGameAsRejected` command to `Player A`; then `Player A` raises the `GameFailed` event and updates its internal state as `not_playing`.
- If the `Player B` is not playing another game then it raises the `GameAccepted` event; the `Game` saga catches this event and send the `MarkGameAsAccepted` command to `Player A` aggregate; `Player A` then emits the `GameStarted` event and update its internal state as `playing`.

In order to understand this you should try to model the use-case as if no computers would exist and players would be humans that communicate over printed mail.

This solution is scalable and I understand that this is required.

**The other solution doesn't seem doable for milion of players**.

**A third solution** would be to use a colection of active players in a SQL table or a NoSQL colection, without using the Aggregate tactical pattern. For concurency, when setting a pair of players as active, you could use optimistick locking  or transactions where supported (low scalable) or two-phase commits (kind of ugly).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're right, I also brainstormed which events I would need. But the question is rather IF I should go for the events-approach at all or elaborate another concept to enforce consistency, for example a "collection of active games"-aggregate. The events-approach seems too complex and scattered and the collection-aggregate-approach seems model-obscuring and maybe inefficient. So my question is concept-concerned rather than a implementation details issue.

Comment: You need to take performance into consideration. With my answer there is no need for a central collection of all player, hence is scalable. The collection architecture is not scalable:  you mentioned milions of players.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the reason why I dislike the collection-approach; but there would be ways to avoid loading all the active games at once but selectively check the existence of according active games retrieved by players instead - but yes, we kind of fall back to the performance issues eventual consistency was supposed to solve. And I'm concerned about the fact that the Player does not express his own availability and is therefore attached to a higher context (maybe the system itself) which hosts the single instance of GameManager (or ActiveGames or whatever proper name).

Comment: Wouldn't it feel more natural if the `Player` AR wouldn't be responsible for raising the `GameRequested` event. To me it seems like it would be better if a command starts the `Game` process manager rather than an event from the `Player`?

Comment: Sagas do not emit events.

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU Thanks. Now I wonder how "transient relationships" are solved in general with DDD. There should be many cases in which multiple components (aggregates) should constitute a unit for a while and then be resolved again. This intricate event-handshake seems not suitable for this kind of "traversal relationship". Do you know if there is a best practice?

Comment: Are you saying that there are cases when two or more aggregates should be persisted in a single transaction?

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU Kind of. But this would indicate wrong aggregate boundaries. Consider a simple *transient* 1:1 relationship which implies to ensure not to assign other components to an already assigned component. How would you solve this without having two transactions?

Comment: Just like you would to it in the real world; let's suppose a man wants to be engaged to a woman that is in a remote town. The man sets himself as engaged then it goes to the other town and ask the woman to engage him. If she already engaged another man then our man would set himself as free. If not, they both will become engaged to each other.

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU Ok, I guess it's just a necessary evil with trade-off considerations.

Comment: As always. Anyway, DDD is nice because the code/architecture *looks* like real world/business.